# MAC , PHP:Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 (Method Not Allowed)

Tags: php, html, macos

I updated my mac os to Mojave and now my PHP codes are not working in a browser.
I checked PHP is installed.
I tried XAMPP and apache, still not working. the error is:
This page isn’t working If the problem continues, contact the site owner.
HTTP ERROR 405.
-Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 (Method Not Allowed).
it's a simple code since I'm a beginner :

```
<?php
echo "<h2>PHP is Fun!</h2>";
echo "Hello world!<br>";
echo "I'm about to learn PHP!<br>";
echo "This ", "string ", "was ", "made ", "with multiple parameters.";
?>
```

Comment: Possibly [a duplicate](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/338099/php-not-working-after-upgrading-to-os-mojave)

Comment: When I run it with localhost it shows a blank page but when I run it manually shows that error.

Comment: Last login: Mon Dec 10 11:17:29 on ttys000
nat-wireless-guest-reg-153-50:~ nadi$ httpd -v
Server version: Apache/2.4.34 (Unix)
Server built:   Aug 17 2018 16:29:43
nat-wireless-guest-reg-153-50:~ nadi$ sudo apachectl start
Password:
/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist: service already loaded
nat-wireless-guest-reg-153-50:~ nadi$  , also local host says: it works!